# Date of release from 1-jan-xx year until now

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I create query which display all item which is cancel in period
`start.date` - `end.date`

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2) as tarifa, count(*) as komada
from pol p, uvod u, doppov d
WHERE (datum_dop >='1-jan-07')  AND (datum_dop<='1-jul-13')
and  izdavanje>='01-jul-10'
and p.orgjed = u.sorgz  (+)
and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)
```

Now I want to edit this query column `izdavanje`. If user enter '27-sep-xx year' it need to display item in period `start-date` '01-jan-xx' until '27-sep-xx year'
So start date need to be always '1-jan-xx year' and end date need to be entered date like '19-aug-xx'.
Any idea how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
and  izdavanje>='01-jul-10'
```

will become

```
and  izdavanje between to_date('01.01.' || substr(:BLOK.IZDAVANJE, -2), 'dd.mm.rr')
                   and to_date(:BLOK.IZDAVANJE, 'dd-mon-rr')
```

- `substr` will return `xx` year
- `to_date` will convert the whole value into a valid date

Now, as it is Forms, you might need to adjust it a little bit (depending on column datatype as well as form item's datatype), but - that's the general idea.

Comment: Look at general solution for this first query when I transfer this query into Oracle Form Builder

Comment: I'm not sure what should I look at. I told you what to do; why did you leave the `and  izdavanje>='01-jul-13'` unmodified?

Comment: @Thank you. I get it :) 
This is old query that's why it's now modified :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `TRUNC( date_value, 'YY' )` to truncate it to the start of the year:

```
AND  izdavanje BETWEEN TRUNC( '01-jul-10', 'YY' ) AND '01-jul-10'
```

However, you should also note that `'01-jul-10'` is a text literal so, when a date is required, Oracle has to perform an implicit conversion from the text literal to a date. You would be better performing an explicit conversion (as Oracle's default format is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and **ANY** user can change this value in their own session and changing that will break your query without any modification of your code).

For example, to perform an explicit cast to a date:

```
AND izdavanje BETWEEN TRUNC(
                        TO_DATE( '01-jul-10', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' ),
                        'YY'
                      )
              AND     TO_DATE( '01-jul-10', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' )
```

Also, if your `izdavanje` date values have time components then `'01-jul-10'` will be converted to a date at midnight (`00:00:00`) so you will not get any values returned for that day that have time components between `2010-07-01 00:00:01` and `2010-07-01 23:59:59`. If this is relevant and you want those values returned then you should use:

```
AND izdavanje >= TRUNC(
                   TO_DATE( '01-jul-10', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' ),
                   'YY'
                 )
AND izdavanje <  TO_DATE( '01-jul-10', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' )
                   + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify a date inside a query using TO_CHAR() function:

Instead of:

```
and  izdavanje>='01-jul-10'
```

use this:

```
and izdavanje between TO_CHAR( :BLOK.IZDAVANJE, 'YYYY-01-01' )
    and TO_CHAR( :BLOK.IZDAVANJE, 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59' )
```

`TO_CHAR( :BLOK.IZDAVANJE, 'YYYY-01-01' )` takes only the year from the date and adds '-01-01' (January 1st) to it.

`TO_CHAR( :BLOK.IZDAVANJE, 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59' )` adds the max time of the day to the date because 'between xxx and yyy' means equal or less than 00:00:00 of day yyy and all timestamps with a timestamp greater than 00:00:00 but the same day won't be covered when using time values in :BLOK.IZDAVANJE.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` is a [Oracle Business Intelligence function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780) and is not available in standard SQL. `DATE_FORMAT` is also a [MySQL function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), however the OP has tagged the question as Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, you're right MT0. I lost sight of the tags above. I modified my answer so that TO_CHAR() is used instead of DATE_FORMAT().